# Count function error (wrong result size)

Tags: r, count, dplyr

I am having a weird problem using `count` function introduced today. When I type:

```
a <- count(data, c("col1", "col2")
```

error popping up

> Error: wrong result size

Earlier this code was working fine. Any help will be appreciated.

```
e.g data <- matrix((1,2,1,2,1,3,1,3,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5), nrow=8, ncol=2)
```

Comment: How about showing a small reproducible example?

Comment: simply have car evaluation dataset, this code was working earlier

Comment: It works fine using this example: `count(mtcars, c("mpg", "cyl"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most default `dplyr` functions are made to use `data.frame` column names unquoted ([non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html)). Hadley builds in standard eval versions, as well, which have the same name, but an underscore (`_`) at the end: in this case, `count_()`. The standard eval ones can use quoted values arranged like yours above:

```
count_(mtcars, c('cyl', 'gear'))
```

Really, the standard-eval versions are overkill unless you need to pass a variable that stores a name, though. In this case, the normal non-standard eval version will work neatly, and produce the same thing, while saving you from typing a few quotes:

```
count(mtcars, cyl, gear)
```

Either way, you get

```
Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
Groups: cyl [?]

    cyl  gear     n
  (dbl) (dbl) (int)
1     4     3     1
2     4     4     8
3     4     5     2
4     6     3     2
5     6     4     4
6     6     5     1
7     8     3    12
8     8     5     2
```

For more detail, see the above link, though it goes into WAY more specifics than you likely need for now.

Comment: thank you, do you know the exact issue because ealier it was working

Comment: Your syntax must have been different, or you were using the SE version. The only ways to get quoted values to work in the NSE version are a good bit of work.

Comment: i have got a final solution, i need to detatch libraries after use